# command line utility to inform what files have changed and display the changes

Tags: command-line

I am wondering if there is a command line utility that shows which files have changed and what are the changed files.

Say in a. directory, there are following files:

```
main.cpp
Solver.hpp
Solver.cpp
Grad.hpp
Grad.cpp
heelers.h
```

say if I append a line, like `std::cost << "hello!" << "\n";` at the end of `Grad.cpp`

and I was wondering if there is a command line utility that shows me what changed from before and what the change is.
Esentially,

```
File(s) changed:
Grad.cpp
Change(s):
line no. std::cost << "hello!" << "\n
```

I understand that there is git diff but I want to do this without committing any changes. Essentially say I saved all of my work at 09:40 am and at 09:45 am, I only changed one file, I want to know which file was changed when compared to 09:40 am. and I only care about the last change. That is, if a file changes at 09:50, I only want to compare it with 09:45 change.

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: macOS is my OS of choice.

Comment: You will need an SCCS to get what you want.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_Code_Control_System .  I'd go for Jörg Schilling's.